# Cannot remove grey bar at bottom of Tor Browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

Yesterday, I accidentally pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and another key which I do not remember anymore. This triggered my Tor Browser to look like this:

[image]

How can I get rid of this grey bar at the bottom?

Comment: go into `about:config` and disable `privacy.resistFingerprinting.letterboxing` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like Tor Browser's letterboxing feature: https://support.torproject.org/tbb/maximized-torbrowser-window/

This probably happened when you resized the window. If you make the window slightly taller, the webpage should fill in the bottom section.

Comment: Well, the thing is that I know what these bars are for but every time I restart the Tor Browser, the window size gets set back to its original size. Before the incident, there has never been a grey bar at the bottom. So, what happened?

Comment: Did you always have the menu bar and bookmark bar enabled? These aren't enabled by default in the Tor Browser. If you disable them, I'm guessing that the grey border will disappear at the normal window size.

Comment: Yes. But even with these things activated, the big grey bar at the bottom did not occur in the past.

Answer (score 0):

**** I solved this problem earlier, if it can help another person I would be happy **
menu.customized, deactivate the title bar (bottom right) **

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the letterboxing feature which is used to avoid fingerprinting.
Try going to [**`about:config`**](http://about:config), and turn `privacy.resistFingerprinting.letterboxing` to false to get rid of it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).