# View tor full-page

Tags: configuration

when I open tor in full page I see a kind of giant footer instead of the classic bar at the bottom, please viw my attached image (tage here). do you know how to remove or how I can decrease the size?[image: example for my favorite site]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot remove grey bar at bottom of Tor Browser](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/21298/cannot-remove-grey-bar-at-bottom-of-tor-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an intentional feature called letterboxing to improve privacy: https://support.torproject.org/tbb/maximized-torbrowser-window/

> Tor Browser in its default mode is starting with a content window rounded to a multiple of 200px x 100px to prevent fingerprinting the screen dimensions. The strategy here is to put all users in a couple of buckets to make it harder to single them out. That works so far until users start to resize their windows (e.g. by maximizing them or going into fullscreen mode). Tor Browser 9 ships with a fingerprinting defense for those scenarios as well, which is called [Letterboxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterboxing_%28filming%29), a technique developed by Mozilla and [presented in 2019](https://www.zdnet.com/article/firefox-to-add-tor-browser-anti-fingerprinting-technique-called-letterboxing/). It works by adding white margins to a browser window so that the window is as close as possible to the desired size while users are still in a couple of screen size buckets that prevent singling them out with the help of screen dimensions.
>
> In simple words, this technique makes groups of users of certain screen sizes and this makes it harder to single out users on basis of screen size, as many users will have same screen size.

If you are not concerned about privacy, you can disable this feature in your `about:config` settings by setting `privacy.resistFingerprinting.letterboxing` to `false`.

Comment: Thanks, it's work!!